# Escape HTML tags in XAML code

Tags: html, xml, escaping

How can escape html tags into a xaml code?

For example, if i want to show `<b>text</b>` in an xaml content to put into a RichTextBox as following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string mystring = "<b>test</b>";
        MyRTB.Blocks.Add(Convert(@"<Bold>" + mystring + "</Bold>"));
    }

        static public Paragraph Convert(string text)
    {
        String formattedText = ParaHead + text + ParaTail;
        Paragraph p = (Paragraph)XamlReader.Load(formattedText);
        return p;
    }
```

I tried with multiple combinations of {} and {} and etc but doesnt work, and I dont want use hexa scape if i can do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to XML-escape it by replacing `<` with `&lt;`.
The built-in `SecurityElement.Escape` or `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` functions will do that for you.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Also for someone who is interested, in Silverlight is: HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: That method is also available in ASP.Net.

Comment: What about esacping not HTML but XAML? (Like with dynamic control templates)?

Comment: @Jaans: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @SLaks: I assume you are a aware that you can dynamically create, compile and execute a XAML string using `XamlReader.Load()`. So just as above where you can have HTML in XAML that you might want to escape, so too can you have XAML in XAML that you want to escape. I'm guessing that because XAML is close to XHTML, I should be able to get away with just using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`... holding thumbs. Hope that explains it.

Comment: @Jaans: You should build that using a propert XML API, not by manually concatenating and escaping strings.  XLINQ is very simple and easy-to-use.